# Control of solutions to nonlinear elliptic equations away from boundary

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb R^3$ with a smooth boundary. Consider a smooth real valued function $F:\overline\Omega \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with the property that $\partial_s F(x,s)\geq 0$ for all $x \in \Omega$ and all $s\in \mathbb R$. Consider the following boundary value problem
$$-\Delta u + F(x,u) =0 \quad \text{on $\Omega$} \quad \text{subject to $u|_{\partial \Omega}=f$}.$$

It is well known that the above problem is well posed in the sense that given any $f \in C^{2,\alpha}(\partial \Omega)$ the above problem admits a unique solution in $C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega)$.

My question is as follows: Given a general nonlinear function $F$ as above and any $p\in \Omega$ and any $\lambda>0$ is it true that there exists $f \in C^{2,\alpha}(\partial \Omega)$ such that the solution $u$ to the above elliptic equation satisfies: $|u(p)|>\lambda$? Even the case of nonlinear functions $F(x,s)= a(x) s^{2k+1}$ with $a$ positive and $k\geq 1$ would be very interesting for me.

Thanks,

Comment: If we put your equation in the standard form (i.e. as a positive definite form) $$ G(\partial_{i,j} u, \partial_i u, u, x)  = \Delta u - F(x,u) = 0 $$ then the result follows from a standard maximum principle, but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: I want the solution at any one point inside to be arbitrarily large for some dirichlet data. How does this follow from maximum principle?

Comment: I apologize for I have misread your question: however, the answer is no again be the maximum principle. Let me explain: your PDE satisfies a maximum principle and this implies that its solutions of PDEs do not attain local/global maximums nor minimums *inside its domain of definition*. In other words the maximum values of the solutions are attained on the boundary thus are defined by the Dirichlet data $f$: if this is $C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega)$, the solution to your equation cannot blow up.

Comment: I also apologize I am not able to write down a full answer since I am far away from my library and thus I cannot give proper references.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri
Thanks but I think you are misreading my question again. For instance it is known that the answer to my question is affirmitive for Lipschitz nonlinearities F in the u variable.

Comment: It is not about attaining maximum inside. For instance think about this example: you consider the p to be the origin and then the question asks whether you can cook up a solution that is of value bigger than \lambda at the origin for lambda very large. It is not beyond unreasonable that if you put Dirichlet data 100\lambda on the boundary then maybe the solution at the origin will be of size roughly lambda. This would not contradict maximum principle.

Comment: To summarize I think your confusion comes because you think I am asking for just one f that does the job. But f depends on p and lambda.

Comment: I have read again your question and I saw my mistake. You need a Dirichlet data $f$ such that, *for an arbitrarily chosen* $p\in\Omega\setminus\partial\Omega$, $|u(p)|>\lambda$. These results are commonly known as *pointwise estimates*: I googled it a bit and I found only a work by Kresin and Maz'ya where the gradient of the solution of a parabolic equation is estimated by the value of the normal derivative at the boundary, and even in this case it is a bound *tout court*, not a lower bound. Perhaps, asking to Vladimir Maz'ya would be a nice idea.